# How can i remove memory warning level=2

Tags: ios4

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
 {

     UITouch *firstTouch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint firstPoint = [firstTouch locationInView:drawImage];

     NSLog(@"drawimage retain coount touches began: %i",[drawImage retainCount]);

     lastPointX = firstPoint.x;
     lastPointY = firstPoint.y;
 }

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
 {

     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
     CGPoint movePoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
     [drawImage.image drawInRect:drawImage.bounds];

     CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
     CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), value);
     CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), t1, t2, t3, 1);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPointX, lastPointY);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
     CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
     CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

     drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


     lastPointX = movePoint.x;
     lastPointY = movePoint.y;

     NSLog(@"drawimage retain coount touches moved: %i",[drawImage retainCount]);

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint movePoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:drawImage.bounds];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), value);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), t1, t2, t3, 1);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPointX, lastPointY);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    NSLog(@"drawimage retain coount touches end: %i",[drawImage retainCount]);



}
```

Here I am getting memory warning level=2. How can I remove that warning?

Answer (score 1):

`retainCount` is useless.  Don't call it.

> Here I am getting memory warning level=2. How can I remove that
>   warning?

Allocate less memory or free the memory you've allocated.  :)

Run your app under the Allocations Instrument and reproduce the problem.  Then check to see exactly what objects are being allocated and not freed (or what is being allocated that is huge).

The code shown may or may not be the problem;   probably not, but impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: Thank you for your response,Here drawImage is taking huge memory,When i release([drawImage release]) this in dealloc, it did not release, how can release this drawImage?